# Why do I sometimes need to merge after a pull rather than simply updating?

Tags: mercurial, merge

When I first started using hg, update seemed to have an almost magical ability to take newly-pulled changes and integrate them into my local repo. Lately, however, I notice that even if my local changes are non-conflicting with the newly-pulled changes from somewhere else, I always have to merge, resulting in an extra changeset that duplicates a bunch of changes I already have in one of my local codelines (heads).

I want to understand what it is that provokes hg to require a merge, instead of just smooshing all the changes together with update. A conflict should clearly require a merge. What else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The need to merge vs. update isn't about whether or not the changes conflict, it's about whether you have a split in your commit history.  If you have a history like this:

```
[A]--[B]--[C]--UNCOMMITTEDCHANGESHERE
```

and you pull down --[D] your uncomitted changes will be combined with D when you update.

If, however you have committed so that you have:

```
[A]--[B]--[C]--[E]
```

and you pull you'll have:

```
[A]--[B]--[C]--[E]
             \
              -[D]
```

and you'll need to merge to get down to a single head.

For the record, that's a better idea.  Updating with uncommitted changes is a non-reversible action, which is always a little scary.  If you've committed, you can always undo/redo a merge until you're happy with the combination.

P.S.  Someone is probably going to suggest the `fetch` extension, and they're dead wrong.

Comment: So on a related note -- if I rebase instead of merging, does that maintain a single contiguous codeline? I noticed that hgsubversion requires this if you want to be able to push back to SVN, and that makes more sense in light of this information.

Comment: Rebasing does yield a linear history, but it's a slightly dishonest linear history (because the development wasn't linear; it was concurrent).  Some people prefer that, but I rather my history truly and accurately reflect the order in which things were committed.  It's all about personal preference (or team policy) in the end.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is fetch 'dead wrong'? I know it's deprecated but not why

Comment: Fetch conflates 3 completely separate actions (`pull`, `update` and `merge`) and produces a useless commit message at the same time.  With a DVCs moving changesets here and there (push/pull in mercurial and push/fetch with git) are logically distinct from updating the working directory and merging the heads.  When you do all 3 with one command you get crappy error semantics, bad commit messages, and if you're starting out likely some confusion around just which commands alter local files, local repos, and remote repos.